# C# Error "Could not load file or assembly" Crystal Report Viewer in Client PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I added file .rpt to my installer setup

but when client access report viewer in my application , getting error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecision.Shared,
>   Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

the application works on my pc, but does not work on user's pc. I try to compile the app in other development machine and it is work well, the problem is my app doesn't work on user's pc.

What components should I add that the pc client can access a crystal report viewer ?

Comment: check your visual-studio and crystal report version, check another component like 32 or 64bit, library component, etc

Comment: What components should I add that the pc client can access a crystal report viewer ? @bxc00zzy